# react nativeでpretterとeslintを使用するときのコード整形について

Tags: javascript, vscode, reactjs, typescript, react-native

**解決したいこと**

1. 拡張子.jsで書くreact nativeのpretterとeslintでのコード整形について
2. typescriptで書くときに悩まされる下記のerrorについて

**前提**

react native を書いています。コード整形でpretterとeslintを使用しています。

**問題**

ここでうまく行かないことがあります。
ファイルの拡張子を.js でreact nativeを書くと下記のようになり使いものになりません。
一方拡張子を.tsxで書くと

**stack2.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Stack2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            View style = {
                { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' } } >
            <
            Text > Stack2 < /Text> <
            /View>
        );
    }
}
```

一方拡張子を.tsxで書くと、下記の部分でerrorがでて先に進めません。
**JSX 要素型 'View' にはコンストラクトも呼び出しシグネチャも含まれていません。**

```
<View></View>
```

拡張子.tsxでは下記のようにちゃんと整形できます。

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Stack2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Stack2</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

**考察**

このことからtypescriptで書くと整形できて、javascriptでは整形ができていないと考えます。

**嘆き**

私はtypescriptでのerrorが解決できないので、拡張子.jsで書きたいのです。ですがコード整形がうまくいきません。

教えて下さい！(m__m)